# How to send SQLite data from one table to several ListViews

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

This is how I currently display the data from the table

```
 ArrayList<String>ar=new ArrayList<>();
    ar=db.getAllScores();
    ArrayAdapter<String>ap=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ar);
        scorebox1.setAdapter(ap);
```

So there is that array-list that stores the lines coming from the table by the getAllScores(); and then ArrayAdapter is displaying the strings in the listView. But I have 2 more listViews that depending on how the string starts that I take from the table I want to send it to the correct one of those 3 listViews. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would write queries that extract the relevant data, perhaps using a **`WHERE`** clause, and very much copying the above for the other ListViews. e.g.

```
ArrayList<String> arother = new ArrayList<>();
arother = db.getOtherScores();
ArrayAdapter<String> apother = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arother);
otherscorebox1.setAdapter(apother);
```

So rather than sending the data to one of three, you get the data for all three in three stages by taking advantage of the power of queries.

Comment: Aha I will pass back to the method a value to search for in the queries and display them with separate arraylists and adapters right ?

Comment: Each will have it's own arraylist, Each would have a unique instance of the same adapter. The example, would compliment the existing code, sho shows these two. Additionally I would normally I write my queries so that I can pass WHERE clause (or extra where clause parameters) but it could depend upon the complexity of the query. the example assumes a separate query.